Delete row if they is no reference left
Consider the following script:
drop table if exists foo;
drop table if exists bar;

create table bar (
  a character varying(10),
  c int auto_increment,
  primary key (c),
  index bar_index (a)
);

create table foo (
  a character varying(10),
  c character varying(10),
  primary key (a),
  foreign key (a) references bar (a) on delete cascade
);

insert into bar (a) values ("A");
insert into bar (a) values ("A");

insert into foo (a, c) values ("A", "xxx");

delete from bar where c=1;

select count(*) from bar;

--- results in 1

delete from bar where c=2;

select count(*) from bar;

--- results in 0

The foreign key construction basically says

If there is no row with a = "A" left in foo, delete every row in bar with a = "A".

This works in MySQL < 8.4. But MySQL 8.4 brings a more restrictive behavior and the second table can not be created.
I am aware that they brought a switch as well to turn this off again. The above script works with MySQL 8.4 and SET restrict_fk_on_non_standard_key = OFF; as expected. But this seems to be only a temporary solution because this is marked as deprecated.
Is there any other reasonable solution to reconstruct the desired behavior within the restrictions of MySQL 8.4? Otherwise I would just check manually and delete them if necessary.
References:

https://www.skeema.io/blog/2024/05/14/mysql84-surprises/#foreign-key-restrictions
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_restrict_fk_on_non_standard_key


The FK reference to a non-unique index is non-standard extension, so you should avoid such constructions. Use trigger logic if necessary.

This requirement usually indicates poor normalization in the DB design.
